# Android : Error when adding radio group programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I am having an error that I don't understand what does it mean. I am kindly new to Android

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I am trying to add a radio group to a table layout programmatically

first I add the radio group to the table layout and i add the radio button to the radio group

```
RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
mRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
TableLayout mainTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);
mainTable.addView(mRadioGroup);
```

Then I create a row and add the radio group to this row and finally ad the row to the table layout

```
TableRow row;
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioButton.setId(1);
radioButton.setText("SomeText");
row.addView(mRadioGroup);

mainTable.addView(row);
```

Can any one help ?

EDIT : It worked when i added the radio group directly on the table layout not on a table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were adding `mRadioGroup` to both `mainTable` and `row`:

```
mainTable.addView(mRadioGroup);
...
row.addView(mRadioGroup);
```

As you partly discovered, **remove either one of these lines** and it will work.

You *don't* have to add a `View` to a `TableRow` in order to add it to a `TableLayout`, but it behaves differently depending on whether or not you do.

Also, you never actually initialized `row` - make sure to do

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
```

before you use it!

Comment: thank you Sharkos

i removed one of them and it worked just like i want

I initialize the row before this code